# How do I bind a button and a label

Tags: c#, winforms, button, label

I extended the button control to have also LabelName. When I press the button I need to write the name of the button in the label.
My first idea was using events - easy and simple.
The question is: Is there more elegant way to do it? (I've been asked to bind the button and the label)...

Comment: If the action that triggers the writing in the label is the button click then you have no better choice than the button click event. Perhaps if you show your actual code we could find 'more elegant ways' to write that code

Comment: If you extend the `Button` and want to do something with it on its click you have no necessary to subscribe to its own event you can just override the `OnClick` method.

Comment: Do you mean you want to set the .Text property of an **external** associated Label control?...and want to store a reference to that Label inside your Button?

Comment: Seems to be an academic question.

Comment: Ok, it seems the OnClick event of button is the way, I'll use it as it. @sudheeshix: This is not academic question but something I asked to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best way to do it would be to use an action listener and the best way to use the action listener would be to build it into your class that extends the button control so that the user doesn't have to do this on their own. It would look like this.

```
class Button2 : Button
{
    public string LabelName = "";
    public Button2()
    {
        this.Click += this.SetLabelName;
    }
    private void SetLabelName(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.LabelName = "Something?";
    }
//You could also do this instead.
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnClick(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That what I thought I should do... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about changing the `Text` property of an **external** Label control, then simply create a property in your Button to hold a reference to a Label.  You can set this via the IDE like any other property:

[image: Setting the associated Label for the Button]

Here's the Button class:

```
public class MyButton : Button
{

    private Label _Label = null;

    public Label Label
    {
        get { return _Label; }
        set { _Label = value; }
    }

    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClick(e);
        if (this.Label != null)
        {
            this.Label.Text = this.Name;
        }
    }

}
```

Here's the Label after I clicked the Button:

[image: The Label after clicking the Button]

Comment: This isn't what I meant, because I need to "bind" for the button only the text but not all the label.